# Can I play a Switch Fortnite account on PS4?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I see a lot of information in the opposite direction: if you have a PS4 linked epic account you can't use it on Switch. However I'm wondering if you played on Switch first can you *then* play on PS4?

Comment: Even if you could, once you link your account to PS4, you wouldn't be able to play it on Switch anymore (or any other console for that matter).

Comment: An Epic account is free, why not test it out and let us know!

Comment: The reason you always see it the other way is simply because PS4 version was out first. So when everyone tried playing on Switch they found out it wasn't possible.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill This has always been true. If you play on Xbox One / Switch, you can't use that account on PS4 and vice versa.  PC, iOS, and (soon) Android are the only systems that can play using any Fortnite account.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can link your accounts. In order to do that, you have to go to [epicgames.com](https://epicgames.com) with a PC*, sign in, go to "account", then "CONNECTED ACCOUNTS", and then link it from there.NOTE: there is a small possibility that you will lose your progress, so I suggest that you link it with a test account first

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and the answer is no, you cannot log in to your epic account on PS4 if you've used it on the Nintendo Switch

Comment: they fixed it so that now you can log in with any platform, as long as you link it